# Git: How to check if the diff the CI is running is having file modified outside src (!src/**)

Tags: bash, git, diff, circleci, git-diff

Using `git`, how within a Circle CI job, can I know if the diff we are building for is including change outside `src`.

I would like to kill the CI if the change are only made into `src`.

What command can I use to check if something else than `src` changed in the current CI?

Comment: "the change" actually implies "the change with respect to *something*" ; can you please define that *something* ? changes in `src/` when comparing the current commit to *what* ?

Comment: Our flow is PR to `master`, so I believe since the last commit on `master` of the last pull request. I've checked in the CI documentation and it seems that the information is not present in the environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
git diff --name-only <something> HEAD | grep -v "^src/"
```

and either

- check if there are some rows,
- or check the final return code (success = there are some changes outside of `src/`, failure = no changes outside of `src/`)

---

To compare the current commit to the point where it forked from master, use :

```
git diff --name-only master...HEAD    # 3 dots
```

*[update]*

One note : `git diff master...HEAD` implies that you have all the repo's history on your local clone (or at least : enough commits in your current branch and the `master` branch to go up to the fork point of these branches).

This will not be the case on your CI server if you have activated some "sparse checkout" or "shallow clone" option in your CI job, which explicitly only fetch the last commit locally.

You can explicitly "deepen" the history for a branch :

```
git fetch --deepen=1000 origin master
git fetch --deepen=1000 origin [active branch]
```

And if you don't check out `master` locally, you may have to compare against `origin/master` instead :

```
git diff --name-only origin/master...HEAD
```

---

If you have shallow clone issues, you may also want to look into the API of your git server.

For example : using github's API, if you have the identifier of the pull request, you can use [Pulls : list files](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests-files) to get the list of files modified by that pull request.

Comment: I understand that I need to determine in Circle CI the hash of the last commit before the first one from my PR so I can do the diff from there, do you know how I can do for this one too ? Maybe there's an [environment variable](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#built-in-environment-variables) from Circle we can use

Comment: Do you have a documentation reference for the `master...HEAD`  ? How can I ensure this will pick only the diff since the last PR ?

Comment: Also, we must be able to reply the pipeline, will this cause issue after not being the ... HEAD ?

Comment: I have just tested `git diff --name-only master...HEAD` within a circle ci in ssh and it returns nothing, while there must be a  diff since the last PR, any clue why ?

Comment: What's the checked out commit ?

Comment: also : `git diff master...HEAD` implies that you have all the repo's history on your local clone (or at least : enough commits in your current branch and the `master` branch to go up to the fork point of these branches). This will not be the case on your CI server if you have activated some "sparse checkout" or "shallow clone" option in your CI job, which explicitly only fetch the last commit locally.

Comment: The checked out commit is `CIRCLE_SHA1`. Reading your last comment, I assume that I could just `git pull origin HEAD` to get the HEAD from the current branch (here `master`). Then running that command will do what exactly ? How can I be sure that it will do the diff from `CIRCLE_SHA1` to the commit that is from the previous pr of `CIRCLE_SHA1`?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa : `HEAD` is a git name for "the current checked out commit". If you want to use `CIRCLE_SHA1`, you perfectly can : `git diff origin/master...$CIRCLE_SHA1`

Comment: "The previous sha" : that would be a CircleCI feature. I don't think a CI framework (which is prbably intended to run several jobs concurrently, from distinct contributors) has a use for "the sha of the last build" (it could be anything). You will have to choose a way to define what "the previous sha" is, and a way to store it and access it.

Comment: So there is no easy way to know what is the diff between two PR? I may use github api or something like that to retrieve the PR I need, and the commit.

Comment: I Just tried with `if git diff --name-only $BASE_SHA..$CIRCLE_SHA | grep -vE "^(src|web)/" ; then
    echo "Command succeeded"
else
    echo "Command failed"
fi` and it always succed